# Is the code folding customizeable in ideolog?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

There are some customization options for custom log files in ideolog. There is also a code folding feature. Can this code folding be customized? I want to set a String/regex for a 'begin folding' and 'end folding' token.

Comment: Check existing / file new at Idealog plugin Issue Tracker: https://github.com/JetBrains/ideolog/issues